# Limiting user input in a UITextField to a certain range of numbers (not number of characters)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I would like to limit user input in a UITextField to 1-105. I have set the delegate and have successfully limited the actual number of characters via the following code, found elsewhere on Stackoverflow. Is there something that I can add in order to force the user to input any integer between 1 and 105?

```
#define MAXLENGTH 2

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSUInteger oldLength = [_startLevel.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;

    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= MAXLENGTH || returnKey;
}
```

I am using the number keypad, so the user is already limited to entering numbers. I just need to find something that will make them input something in the range.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the string to a number. In order of ease of use and lack of control, the ways you do that are `-[NSString integerValue]`<sup>*</sup>, `NSNumberFormatter`, and `NSScanner`. The formatter will give you an `NSNumber` from which you can then get the `integerValue`<sup>*</sup>; the other two get you primitives directly.

Once you have that, compare the number to the endpoints of your range, creating a boolean. Combine that boolean with the other two -- for length and lack of newline -- you already have, and return the result.

---

<sup>*</sup>For floating point, either `floatValue` or `doubleValue`.

Answer (score 0):

In didEndEditing, get the text, convert it to an integer, and check the value. If it's out of range, display an error message. You might also reset the text to it's previous value, assuming it starts out in-range.

I've used a regular expression to validate inputs to the right format.  I found some documentation on line on RegEx that I was able to use to build my expression. You might create a regular expression that requires the input to be 1, 2, or 3 digits. I'm no expert, but the string @"^[0-9]{1,3}$" should require 1 to 3 digits between 0 and 9 (the 0-9 defines the legal characters, and the {1,3} means that the user can enter 1 through 3 of them. The ^ at the beginning anchors the expression to the beginning of the string, and the "$" at the end anchors the expression to the end of the string.)

Comment: @Josh, agreed. I was suggesting using a regex to validate the format, and an explicit range check on the converted value once it passes the format test.

Comment: Ah, gotcha; I didn't quite understand.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below

```
    NSString *numberRegex = @"[1-9]||[0-9][1-9]||[0-1]0[0-5]";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegex];
    BOOL b = [emailTest evaluateWithObject:numberField.text];

    if (b)
    {
        //Code when number is in the range 1-105
    }
    else
    {
        //Code when number is not in the range 1-105
    }
```

Hope this helps you